# Internet Explorer javascript compatibility

Tags: javascript, asp.net, windows-server-2008

I have a simple javascript function to check all checkboxes when a header checkbox is selected.

```
function SelectAll(id) {       
    var grid = document.getElementById("<%=ui_downlinkGrid.ClientID %>");
    var cell;
    if (grid.rows.length > 0)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < grid.rows.length; i++)
        {
            cell = grid.rows[i].cells[0];
            cell.childNodes[1].checked = document.getElementById(id).checked;
        }
    }
}
```

I tested this on IE 9 and it works perfectly. However once I got it on Windows Server 2008, it does not work, and the debugger shows this error: Object doesn't support this property or method.

Is this a compatibility issue? How can I solve this?

EDIT: The error is on this line:

```
cell.childNodes[1].checked = document.getElementById(id).checked
```

[image]

Comment: What version of browser do you have? IE9? It should work then.

Comment: Does the grid element actually have a property named "rows"?

Comment: What version of IE? On what line does the error occur?

Comment: Yes it does. As I mentioned, tested it out on IE9 and worked perfectly.

Comment: The version on the server is IE 8

Comment: Without knowing anything about the markup you're traversing, I think the issue is that `cell.childNodes[1]` isn't the node you think it is. It could be an empty textNode. Can you post a JSFiddle that reveals the bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`childNodes` return text nodes as well as elements, its plausible that you are now hitting a textnode, rather than the input you are attempting to access.  Use `children` or `getElementsByTagName` instead:

The following assumes that there is an element before the `<input>`:

```
cell.children[1].checked = document.getElementById(id).checked;
```